# How do I connect to wifi using only the command line in Manjaro?

Tags: command-line, wifi, manjaro, wpa2

I recently updated my system with Pacman and am getting a `could not start kdeinit5` error message.

After some Googling. It seems I simply need to update Pacman.

However, as I am on Wifi and have no means of connecting via Ethernet. I need to connect to my WPA2-PSK protected network before Pacman will function.

I'm a new Manjaro user. How can I connect to my network?

Comment: Read arch page about netctl it is very clear. Also choose which method to use - just systemd, netctl or nmcli for network manager. All described well in arch wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file;

```
wpa_passphrase Your_SSID Your_Password > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
sed -i '1 i\ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
sed -i '2 i\update_config=1' /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Change `Your_SSID` and  `Your_Password` with yours .

Sart the `wpa_supplicant`:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Replace `<interface>` with yours.

Get an IP through dhcp:

```
dhclient <interface>
```